# allow unique key column to use null value as key instead of ignoring it

Tags: database, graphql, constraints, hasura, unique-key

I am new to using graph ql, and I am trying to set up a unique key for one of my tables.

For context, the table's key will be determined on the combination of part_number + organization_id. So each organization ID can only have one part_number, but different organizations can have the same part_number.

The issue I am running into is that organization_id is a nullable field. When null, this represents global data. So essentially, I want it to act the same as an organization_id.

IE, if I had the part_number: ABC123, I want to enforce that only one of those exist for each organization_id AND only one of those exists for a row with no organization_id.

Currently, I have a unique key set to product_pn_organization_id, and everything works fine for products with an organization ID, but as soon as the organization ID is null graph ql completely ignores the unique key constraint. So when I run an insert mutation with the product_pn_organization_id constraint on a part_number: ABC123 organization_id: null (assuming this already exists) instead of updating the row, it creates a new row.

If I run the same insert with an organization_id (part_number: ABC123, organization_id: 1, again assuming this row already exists) it will update the columns instead of creating a new row.

Right now, the only solution I can think of is creating an organization that represents 'global' and having that as the default organization_id so that organization_id is never actually null. However, I would rather avoid that if possible.

Hoping someone has some advice on how to move forward here. Thanks!

Per request, here are the mutations:

This mutation inserts a new row with organization_id set to null.

```
mutation MyMutation {
  insert_products(objects: {pn: "ABC123", manufacturer_pn: "MANABC123"}, on_conflict: {constraint: products_pn_organization_id_key, update_columns: manufacturer_pn}) {
    returning {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally, this query would update the row from the first query, but instead creates a new row.

```
mutation MyMutation {
  insert_products(objects: {pn: "ABC123", manufacturer_pn: "MANABC124"}, on_conflict: {constraint: products_pn_organization_id_key, update_columns: manufacturer_pn}) {
    returning {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

This query inserts the same PN but with an organization_id.

```
mutation MyMutation {
  insert_products(objects: {pn: "ABC123", manufacturer_pn: "MANABC123", organization_id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}, on_conflict: {constraint: products_pn_organization_id_key, update_columns: manufacturer_pn}) {
    returning {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Unlike the second query, this query actually updates the row belonging to the organization_id/pn combination instead of creating a new row.

```
mutation MyMutation {
  insert_products(objects: {pn: "ABC123", manufacturer_pn: "MANABC124", organization_id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}, on_conflict: {constraint: products_pn_organization_id_key, update_columns: manufacturer_pn}) {
    returning {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the actual mutation(s) that you're using so we can see how you're interacting with the unique constraint?

Comment: Would giving a default value of `0` be an option? It can be non-nullable and have a default for when not supplied...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running on top of a Postgres DB, and you need to update to V 15 to get support for this. More info [here](https://pganalyze.com/blog/5mins-postgres-unique-constraint-null-parallel-distinct), and an excerpt:

> In Postgres 14 and older versions unique constraints always treat NULL
> values as not equal to other NULL values. If you're inserting a NULL
> value into a table and you have a unique constraint, the NULL value is
> considered to be distinct on its own. NULL is always different from
> another NULL. When you're inserting five records into the
> "old_null_style" table where "val1" is just always the same value
> "Hello" and then "val2" is always NULL.
>
> Even though you have a unique constraint that actually supports you
> inserting that five times or as many times as you'd like, because you
> have that NULL value that makes each row distinct from another and
> because the unique constraint includes both "val1" and "val2", all the
> rows are unique.